# equivalency of partition & equivalency relation's definitions

Tags: abstract-algebra

The Algebra book I'm reading says:

> The notion of partition and equivalence relation from a logical point
>   of view are equivalent. Given a partition P of S, it is possible to
>   define an equivalence relation R through the rule: *a ~ b*, if *a* and
>   *b* belong to the same subset of the partition.

Suppose I have the set S={1,2,3,4,5} and the following which form a partition of S: {1,3}, {2,5}, {4}.
What equivalence relation can I define for each partition?
The proof of the theorem is the following:

> Given the subset $S_\alpha$ of the partition, is enough to define the
>   relation:
>
> $ a \,\rho\, b \Longleftrightarrow \exists S_\alpha | a,b \in S_\alpha$
>
> Which is obviously an equivalence relation, which classes are the
>   parts of $S_\alpha$

It is not obvious for me the meaning of the relation and why it is an equivalence one.

Comment: Wouldn't the partition be $\{\{1,3\},\{2,5\},\{4\}\}$?

Comment: To prove the theorem: revisit the definition. Then, from the definition of the relation $R$, verify the requirements (symmetry, transitivy, reflexitivity). For the other way round, given an equivalence relation, you have to show that the set of all $\{a: a\sim b\} $ is a partition...

Answer (score 1):

To get you started with the proof: Suppose you are given a partition $S= \{S_i\}$ and the relation $R$ defined as in your question. You have to show this is an equivalence relation, so you need to verify reflexivity, transitivity and symmetry. I'll show transitivity and let you try to do the rest:

So assume $a\sim b $ and $b\sim c$. This means by definition of $R$ that there is $S_1 $ such that $a\in S_1$ and $b\in S_1$, and (second relation) $S_2$ such that $b\in S_2$ and $c\in S_2$. Since we have a partition, $b\in S_1$ and $b\in S_2$ implies $S_1 = S_2$. So we have $a\sim c$.

Basically you have to recall the definitions and verify them...of course what I have shown is only part of the first direction.

As for the example: you have a partition, so it defines an equivalence relation according to the formula in your question. This just means that you have the relations $1\sim 3, 2\sim 5$, the associated symmetric relations and the trivial ones $a\sim a$ for each $a$. You don't have to find them, they are *defined* by the partition.

(This was the very first exercise I had to solve when I studied math some 30 years ago, so I understand your confusion...)

Comment: If I have understood correctly in all possible cases I can always define the equivalence relation: "elements belonging to the same subset of a partition" thus: 1 ~ 3; 2 ~ 5; 4 ~4 ?

Comment: Also, $1 \sim 1$ etc.